# How to sql for each id?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am running this SQL statement:

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
WHERE id IN (6, 8, 8) 
GROUP BY id
```

I want to get something like this:

```
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 6  | Joe  |
| 8  | Alex |
| 8  | Alex |
```

How to do it? For each id get one found row?

Comment: please specify which `Database` you use too

Comment: I use postgresql

Comment: Repeating the number 8 twice isn't going to make the query return that row multiple times.  It'd be easier to help if you posted some sample data rows from the `users` table - not just the expected results. Since we can't see the raw data, we no idea "why" you expect the query to return multiple rows ...

Comment: id in my table is unique for each record, without duplicates of any row. But i wanna search for squery, that help me, to solve that problem and return separately row on EACH id in request.

Comment: I don't think it is achievable by simple query, writing a stored procedure loop through it and selecting based on input

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Answer (score 1):

If we query one table without using DISTINCT, JOIN or GROUP BY etc. we get the same number or rows returned as there are in the table which meet the WHERE condition if there is one.
We can force duplication by joining to a fictive table with duplicate lines.

> ```
> create table users (id int, name varchar(10));
> insert into users values (4,'Bill'),(6,'Joe'),(8,'Alex');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * 
> FROM users 
> WHERE id IN (6, 8, 8);
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name
> -: | :---
>  6 | Joe 
>  8 | Alex
> ```

> ```
> SELECT u.id, u.name 
> FROM users AS u
> JOIN (
> SELECT 6 AS id
> UNION ALL SELECT 8
> UNION ALL SELECT 8)  AS i 
> ON u.id = i.id
> ```

> ```
> id | name
> -: | :---
>  6 | Joe 
>  8 | Alex
>  8 | Alex
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=bb7452f5abd3cc2873662d7d182b5fc8)*

Comment: This give me 2 rows, but i wanna get 3 rows. I need to get EACH row for each id, that i searched

Comment: You are searching for 2 ID's. Unless there is a duplicate in your table it is normal that you only get 2 rows returned. Are there 2 rows of Id 8?

Comment: Yep, i know that is normal, i search for query, that should help me to get 3 rows. For 6, 8, 8 separetely

Comment: @JesseyPinkman I modified my answer with an example of doing what you want using a join. Is this OK for you? We would use a stored procedure if this is something that you will be using a lot. Perhaps you could explain why you want to duplicate data in the results? Maybe you are going to join onto another table and the duplication will happen automatically.